# Remove invalid UNICODE characters from XML file in UNIX?

Tags: perl, unix, unicode

I have a shell script that I use to remotely clean an XML file produced by another system that contains invalid UNICODE characters. I am currently using this command in the script to remove the invalid characters:

```
perl -CSDA -i -pe's/[^\x9\xA\xD\x20-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]+//g;' file.xml
```

and this has worked so far but now the file has new error of, as far as I can tell, 'xA0', and what happens is my perl command reaches that error in the file and erases the rest of the file. I modified my command to include xA0, but it doesn't work:

```
perl -CSDA -i -pe's/[^\x9\xA0\xD\x20-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]+//g;' file.xml
```

I have also tried using:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 -c file.xml > file2.xml
```

but that doesn't do anything. It produces an identical file with the same errors.

Is there a unix command that I can use that will completely remove all invalid UNICODE characters?

EDIT:
some HEX output (note the 1A's and A0's):

3E 1A 1A 33 30 34 39 37 1A 1A 3C 2F 70

6D 62 65 72 3E A0 39 34 32 39 38 3C 2F

Comment: Please provide a hexdump of a few relevant lines. Btw, if `iconv` isn't stripping them, they probably aren't invalid byte sequences, even if they look like gibberish. Perhaps clarify what you mean precisely by "invalid characters".

Comment: I added what I think you were asking for. the utf-8 codepoint says the A0 is an invalid continuation byte. By invalid i mean removing all non-utf-8 characters.

Comment: 1A is valid ASCII and therefore valid UTF-8. my iconv strips out A0. What version of iconv are you using?

Comment: You may just decode/encode whole file:
`encode("UTF-8",decode("utf8",$content))`

wrong characters would be replaced with "?"

Comment: @jhnc i was using iconv 1, now I tried using iconv 2 and it does strip out A0 (rendered as <A0> but leaves the 1A's (rendered as ^Z). Perhaps I was wrong when saying non-utf-8 characters. My system that ingests the XML that contains 1A spits out an error, saying 'An invalix XML character (Unicode 0x1A) was found'.

It looks like I should be able to use a combination of iconv to remove A0 first then the perl script to remove 1A, now that I know my iconv was outdated. Thanks for that.

Comment: @MonsAnderson I can't replace the characters with ? as that will invalidate the XML file against the XSD. It expects only numbers, so my only option is to remove the invalid characters.

Comment: btw, the 1A may be an indication of erroneous conversion earlier on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following onliner:

```
perl -i -MEncode -0777ne'print encode("UTF-8",decode("UTF-8",$_,sub{""}))' file.xml
```

You also may extend it with warnings:

```
perl -i -MEncode -0777ne'print encode("UTF-8",decode("UTF-8",$_,sub{warn "Bad byte: @_";""}))' file.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

`A0` is not a valid UTF-8 sequence. The errors you were encountering where XML encoding errors, while this one is a character encoding error.

`A0` is the Unicode Code Point for a non-breaking space. It is also the iso-8859-1 and cp1252 encoding of that Code Point.

I would recommend fixing the problem at its source. But if that's not possible, I would recommend using [Encoding::FixLatin](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encoding::FixLatin) to fix this new type of error (perhaps via the bundled `fix_latin` script). It will correctly replace `A0` with `C2 A0` (the UTF-8 encoding of a non-breaking space).

Combined with your existing script:

```
perl -i -MEncoding::FixLatin=fix_latin -0777pe'
   $_ = fix_latin($_);
   utf8::decode($_);
   s/[^\x9\xA\xD\x20-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]+//g;
   utf8::encode($_);
' file.xml
```